# Find the perimeter of the quadrilateral $KLMN$.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

In the figure, determine the perimeter of the quadrilateral $KLMN$.(The answer provided to the problem is : $8\sqrt2$)

[image]

I could find the radii of the circumference but I can't find the sides of the quadrilateral

$\triangle ENB =: sin 45^o  = \frac{4-r_2}{4}\implies \boxed{r_2 = 4-2\sqrt2}$
$\triangle PKF: (4+r_1)^2 -(4-r_1)^2  =B^2 \implies OB = 4\sqrt{r_1}\\
\therefore  \triangle KOE: (4-r_1)^2=r_1^2+(4\sqrt r_1 - 4)^2 \implies\boxed{ r_1 = \frac{16}{9} = r_3}$
$\triangle LNE: (4+r_4)^2=(2\sqrt2)^2+(8-r_4-2\sqrt2)^2 \implies \boxed{r_4 = \frac{40-{16\sqrt2}}{17}}$

$MN = KN$

$ML=KL$

[image]

Comment: Looks like you could find the coordinates of all 4 points from this information, which then gets you the perimeter by finding the length of each side. Length $KP$ might be tough, though.

Comment: @eyeballfrog  The question is to be solved by plane geometry.

Comment: Actually, the diagram is underspecified. Circle $N$ is known to be tangent to circles $E$ and $F$, but that doesn't uniquely specify its position and radius. You have assumed that $ENB$ is a right angle, but that doesn't necessarily follow from the diagram. Could you post the text of the problem accompanying the diagram?

Comment: @eyeballfrog  

The text and diagram of the problem have already been posted. They are exactly like the original. The center of N is on the angle bisector, hence the angle of $45^o$. There is no other possibility.

Comment: @e   The angle bisector through the center is parallel to the tangent of $N$ through $S$

Comment: There's a further problem: the perimeter of triangle $KLM$ is larger than $8\sqrt{2}$, and the perimeter of $KLMN$ must be larger than that of $KLM$.

Comment: The solution provided to the problem is not important. I would like to know the process of calculating the sizes of the sides regardless of the solution provided. (Some solutions provided are not correct, this is not an uncommon fact))

Answer (score 1):

One way to go in such situations is to use inversion w.r.t. to a chosen point that makes the "most complicated circles" to become lines. I will denote by $*$ the inversion in the corner denoted (my notations!) below by $O$, the origin of the axes in the picture, and with power $8^2=64$:

[image: problem math stackexchange 4710695]

Some words on the picture, so that it become less intimidating.
The axes will be used to have a simpler way to address points, i will not make huge cartesian computations. On the $Ox$ axis there are the points $A_1,A_2,A_3,A_4$ placed with step four units. So for instance $OA_2=8$, so w.r.t. inversion star the point $A_2$ is fixed, $A_2=A_2^*$. Also, since
$OA_1\cdot OA_4=4\cdot 16=\left(\frac 12\cdot8\right)\left(2\cdot8\right)=8^2$
the points $A_1$ and $A_4$ correspond w.r.t. star, $A_1^*=A_4$, $A_4^*=A_1$.

The points $B_1,B_2,B_3,B_4$ on the $Oy$ axis correspond to $A_1,A_2,A_3,A_4$ by symmetry w.r.t. the angle bisector of the shown first quadrant.

The piece of paper from the question corresponds to the $8\times 8$ square $OA_2S^*B_2$, here $S^*=(8,8)$. Let $S$ be the point $S=(4,4)$. Then the notation is compatible with the inversion, since $OS\cdot OS^*=4\sqrt2\cdot 8\sqrt 2=8^2$.

There is a violet quarter circle from $A_2$ to $B_2$, and the given picture lives inside the corresponding quarter disk. Insid this region there are:

- the pink circle is $(N)$, centered in $N$, and there is not much to say any longer about $N$, it is simply $N=OSS^*\cap A_1B_1$. The picture above show its transform, but we are not needing this information.
- the blue circle is $(M)$, centered in $M$. It is tangent to $Ox$, the red half-circle $\overset\frown{OSA_2}$, and the green half-circle $\overset\frown{OSB_2}$. It lives inside the half-disk with arc $\overset\frown{OSA_2}$ and outside the other half-disk.
- the orange circle is $(L)$, centered in $L$. It is tangent to the violet quarter circle $\overset\frown{A_2B_2}$, to the red half-circle $\overset\frown{OSA_2}$, and to the green half-circle $\overset\frown{OSB_2}$. It lives inside the quarter-disk with radius $8$, and outside the half-disks with radius $4$.
- there is a reflected blue circle $(K)$, centered in $K$, but we do not really need it. The point $M$ covers the information we also need for $K$.

---

So far we have only identified the given data. Let us transform by inversion.

- The axis $Ox$ is transformed into itself.
- The axis $Oy$ is transformed into itself.
- The violet quarter-circle $\overset\frown{A_2B_2}$ is transformed into itself.
- The red half-circle $\overset\frown{OSA_2}$ is transformed into the half-line $A_2S^*$. It is also marked with red.
- The green half-circle $\overset\frown{OSB_2}$ is transformed into the half-line $B_2S^*$. It is also marked with green.
- The blue circle $(M)$ is tangent to $Ox$, red half-circle, green half-circle. So it is mapped to a circle tangent to $Ox$, red line, green line. There is only one such circle, it fits inside the square $S^*A_2A_4?$, and its center $M'$ projects thus on the axes in $A_2$ and $B_1$.
  (Note that $M'\ne M^*$. For this reason we use a prime to denote the center of a transformed circle. We keep this convention in the sequel.) But $(M)$ and $(M')$ correspond not only through inversion, but also through a similarity centered in $O$. We know the factor of this similarity by considering
  projections on $Ox$, so let us use only one coordinate, the $x$-value for points on this line. Firstly, the projection of $M'$ is $A_2+4=8+4=12$. So the projection of $M$ is by inversion $8^2/12=16/3=12\cdot(4/9)$. So $M$ is $\frac 49 M'=\frac 49(12,4)=\left(\frac {16}3,\frac {16}9\right)$. The radius of $(M)$ is thus the second component, $16/9$, OP denotes it by $r_3$.
- The orange circle $(L)$ is mapped into a circle $(L')$ tangent to the violet arc, the red line, and the blue line.
  Let $D=D^*$ be the point of contact
  the violet arc with $(L)$ and $(L')$, so $D=D^*=4\sqrt 2(1,1)$, the only point
  the point on the angle bisector $OSS^*$ with $OD=8=OA_2=OB_2$.

Many computations on the common line
$ONSLDL'S^*$ of many relevant points will follow, so let us introduce
$$
e =\frac 1{\sqrt 2}(1,1)\ ,
$$
the unit vector on this line with orientation in the first quadrant.
Then we can write simpler for instance $N=2\sqrt 2e$, $S=2N=4\sqrt 2e$,
$D=8e=D^*$, $S^*=8\sqrt 2 e$.

Let now $x$ be the distance from $L'$ to the red vertical or/and green horizontal line/s. It is thus the radius of $(L')$, so also $x=LD$.
And $x\sqrt 2$ is $L'S^*$. This gives
$$(\sqrt 2+1)x=DL'+L'S^*=DS^*=OS^*-OD=8\sqrt 2-8=8(\sqrt 2-1)\ .$$
So
$$x=\frac 1{\sqrt 2+1}8(\sqrt 2-1)=8(\sqrt 2-1)^2=8(3-2\sqrt 2)=24-16\sqrt2\ .
$$
I used the last formula to construct the tangent point of $(L')$ with the green line, by drawing a corresponding parallel to the line trough $S^*$ and $(24,0)$. This is not needed in the computations, but was needed while drawing the picture. Now we have the formula for $L'$, it is on the angle bisector $OSS^*$, $L'=D+xe=(8+x)e=\dots$ $%(32-16\sqrt 2)e=16\sqrt 2(\sqrt 2-1)e$

The point $L'$ is not "compatible" with the inversion, it does not have a "good/relevant" tranform, the interesting point is rather the point $Z$ such that $DZ$ is a diameter of $(L')$. (Not shown in the picture.) It is
$$
\begin{aligned}
Z &=2L'-D=2(D+xe)-D=D+2xe=(8+2x)e=(56-32\sqrt 2)e
\\
&=8(7-4\sqrt 2)e\ ,\\
&\qquad\text{ so by inversion of power $8^2$:}
\\
Z^*&=
\frac8{7-4\sqrt 2}e=\frac 8{49-32}(7+4\sqrt 2)e=\frac 8{17}(7+4\sqrt 2)e\ ,
\\
L 
&=\frac 12(D+Z^*)=4e+\frac 4{17}(7+4\sqrt 2)e
=\frac 4{17}(17+7+4\sqrt 2)e
\\
&=\frac {16}{17}(6+\sqrt 2)e=\frac {16}{17}(3\sqrt 2+1)\cdot(1,1)
\ ,\\
\operatorname{diameter}(\ (L)\ )
&=Z^*D=\left(8-\frac 8{17}(7+4\sqrt 2)\right)=\frac 8{17}(17-7-4\sqrt 2)
\\
&=\frac {16}{17}(5-2\sqrt 2)\ ,
\end{aligned}
$$
which is in OP notations exactly $2r_4$. (This is a the good point to upvote the question, everything was correctly calculated.)

---

---

It remains to find the sides of the quadrilaterals. I see only a simple, direct  way to do that, we project on the axes, $NM$ and $ML$, use the known lengths of the projections and Pythagoras to conclude:
$$
\begin{aligned}
NM^2 &=
\left(\frac {16}3-2\right)^2+
\left(\frac {16}9-2\right)^2
=
\frac {100}9 +\frac4{81}=\frac{904}{9^2}\ ,\\
NM &=\frac{\sqrt{904}}9\approx 3.34073252852731\dots\ ,
\\[2mm]
ML^2 &=
\left(\frac{16}{17}(1+3\sqrt 2)-\frac {16}3\right)^2+
\left(\frac{16}{17}(1+3\sqrt 2)-\frac {16}9\right)^2
\\
&=
\left(\frac{16}{17\cdot 9}\right)^2\cdot
\Big[\ 
\Big( 9(1+3\sqrt 2)-3\cdot 17 \Big)^2
\Big( 9(1+3\sqrt 2)-17 \Big)^2
\ \Big]
\\
&=
\left(\frac{16}{17\cdot 9}\right)^2\cdot
\Big[\ 
4744-2700\sqrt 2
\ \Big]
\ ,\\
ML &= \frac{32}{17\cdot 9}\sqrt{1186-675\sqrt 2}\approx 3.1816009679134\dots
\ ,
\end{aligned}
$$
and the computed values correspond to those shown by geogebra, here we profit from the fact that we have an exact drawing:

[image: math stackexchange 4710695 check picture]

We do not have a beautiful result... So i will stop here.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the most concise approach but I think it's feasible. I didn't obtain $8\sqrt{2}$ as the final answer, though.

- You have $\sin\measuredangle{BEN}$, $\cos\measuredangle{BEN}$, $\sin\measuredangle{OEK}$, and $\cos\measuredangle{OEK}$, so you can figure out $\cos\measuredangle{KEN}$, as $\measuredangle{KEN}=\pi-\measuredangle{BEN}-\measuredangle{OEK}$. With $KE$ and $EN$, applying the law of cosines gives you $KN$.
- It's not difficult to calculate $OB$, and with $OK$, one can easily figure out $\sin\measuredangle{OBK}$ and $\cos\measuredangle{OBK}$, and thus $\cos\measuredangle{KBL}$ as $\measuredangle{KBL}=\frac{\pi}{4}-\measuredangle{OBK}$. It's also straightforward to calculate $BK$ and $BL$, so applying the law of cosines gives you $KL$.

Since $KN=MN$ and $KL=ML$, the perimeter of quadrilateral $KLMN$ is $2(KN+KL)$.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Hint: Considering the figure you can find following measures using the radii you found:

1- $BE=BG-r_4$

2- $LC$ from measures BC, BL and $\angle CBL=45^o$

3- $CP=PB$  and $\angle LCP$ then $LP$.

4- show $PW=r_4$

5- find $\angle PCW$ then $\angle PCW$.

6- $\angle LCW=\angle PCW+\angle LCP$.

7- Find $MC=ML$ from LC and $\angle LCW$

8- Find $\angle KLM$, $LM=LK$ so you can find $KM$

9- Now you have measures of   LN and KM and LM=LK, you can find $ MN=NK$.